# Having troubles rendering rectangle on button press

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to add a `Rectangle` in the panel by button press and remove it with another one. It should work but it doesn't render anything, and I absolutely don't know why.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and give me some nice tips what I can improve with my code?

```
public class GUI extends JPanel {

    public static boolean isRecVisible = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createGui();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2d.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
    }

    public static void createGui() {

        int frameWidth = 550;
        int frameHeight = 400;

        int buttonWidth1 = 250;
        int buttonHeight1 = 30;

        int buttonWidth2 = 500;
        int buttonHeight2 = 30;

        int displayWidth = frameWidth - 20;
        int displayHeight = frameHeight - 105;

        GUI drawRec = new GUI();

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Rectangle");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JPanel display = new JPanel();
        JButton addRec = new JButton("Add Rectangle");
        JButton removeRec = new JButton("Remove Rectangle");
        JButton colorRec = new JButton("Color Rectangle");

        f.add(p);
        p.add(addRec);
        p.add(removeRec);
        p.add(colorRec);
        p.add(display);

        display.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        f.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

        display.setBounds(frameWidth / 2 - displayWidth / 2, 10, displayWidth, displayHeight);
        addRec.setBounds(frameWidth / 2 - buttonWidth1 / 2 - 250 / 2, frameHeight - 85, buttonWidth1, buttonHeight1);
        removeRec.setBounds(frameWidth / 2 - buttonWidth1 / 2 + 250 / 2, frameHeight - 85, buttonWidth1, buttonHeight1);
        colorRec.setBounds(frameWidth / 2 - buttonWidth2 / 2, frameHeight - 60, buttonWidth2, buttonHeight2);

        addRec.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (isRecVisible == false) {
                    isRecVisible = true;
                    display.add(drawRec);
                    display.repaint();
                    System.out.println("Rectangle has been drawn!");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Rectangle has already been drawn!");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

        removeRec.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (isRecVisible == true) {
                    isRecVisible = false;
                    System.out.println("Rectangle has been removed!");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Rectangle has already been removed");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than adding or removing components, it would make more sense here to add the custom painted panel on construction, and use the `isRecVisible` boolean as a flag to test for drawing the rectangle.

Something like shown here:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JPanel {

    public static boolean isRecVisible = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createGui();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (isRecVisible) {
            g2d.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(600,400);
    }

    public static void createGui() {
        int frameWidth = 550;
        int frameHeight = 400;

        GUI drawRec = new GUI();
        drawRec.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Rectangle");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JButton addRec = new JButton("Add Rectangle");
        JButton removeRec = new JButton("Remove Rectangle");
        JButton colorRec = new JButton("Color Rectangle");

        f.add(p, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        p.add(addRec);
        p.add(removeRec);
        p.add(colorRec);
        f.add(drawRec);

        f.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

        addRec.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                isRecVisible = true;
                drawRec.repaint();
            }
        });

        removeRec.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                isRecVisible = false;
                drawRec.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
display.add(drawRec);
display.repaint();
```

When you add (or remove) components to a visible frame then the basic logic is:

```
display.add(...);
display.revalidate();
display.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```

The `revalidate()` is the key method because it invokes the layout manager so the size/location of the component can be set.

However, that still won't fix the problem because your custom panel doesn't have a preferred size, so there is nothing to paint for your component.

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom panel to return the preferred size of your custom component. So in your case you might set the preferred size to be (220, 220) so the rectangle is centered in the panel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html) for more information and complete working examples.

Note: the tutorial example will also show you how to better structure your code to make sure the GUI is created on the Event Dispatch Thread.